# setTimeOut in a getJSON response

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a function that fetches data to display using getJSON :

```
 function getTopClientsMale(){
 var url = "/getData/M";
  $.getJSON(url, function(data){
        document.getElementById("male1").innerHTML=  "<h4><b>"+data[0].client["name"]+" "+data[0].client["lastName"]+"</b></h4><p'>TRAKscore: <b>"+data[0].surveyResults["score"]+"</b></p>";
          });     
   return false;    
}
```

and another function:

```
function getTopClientsFemale(){
 var url = "/getData/F";
  $.getJSON(url, function(data){
    document.getElementById("male1").innerHTML=  "<h4>
<b>"+data[0].client["name"]+" "+data[0].client["lastName"]+"</b></h4>
<p'>TRAKscore: <b>"+data[0].surveyResults["score"]+"</b></p>";
      });     
   return false;    
 }
```

And a getActivityFeed() function that does the same, but calls the latest entered data.

I want to be able to call these functions, every 10 seconds to check if there is an update.
Do I use setInterval or setTimeOut in this case?
They all should refresh the content of the same html.
How do I do that ?
I tried :

```
 var timeout = setTimeOut(getTopClientsMale, 1000);
```

But I'm not sure if that would be the best approach.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest solution is to add a setTimeout when you get the JSON response and after your HTML work.

```
function getTopClientsMale(){
  var url = "/getData/M";
  $.getJSON(url, function(data){
    document.getElementById("male1").innerHTML=  "<h4><b>"+data[0].client["name"]+" "+data[0].client["lastName"]+"</b></h4><p'>TRAKscore: <b>"+data[0].surveyResults["score"]+"</b></p>";
  }).then(function() {
    setTimeout(getTopClientsMale, 10000);
  });     
  return false;    
}
```

If you try setInterval(getTopClientsMale, 10000), what if the API takes more than 10 seconds to answer? An update starts before the previous update finish.

On the other side, this solution doesn't update exactly every 10 seconds. It begins the update work 10 seconds after the previous update ends, so one update starts (10 seconds + time take waiting for response + time take updating HTML) after the previous start.

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

you can use setTimeout/setInterval to schedule the method call with a specified time. But nowadays javascript is async, so be careful while giving the intervals and try to use promises to make async calls better.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the time it will need to execute your call perhaps it is better to have setTimeout in your callback function instead of having interval which will depend on the speed of your response.